# Can't adapt dataset to FeatureSpace

Tags: dataframe, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, data-preprocessing

I'm preprocessing the Kaggle Titanic dataset using a `FeatureSpace` and I'm running into issues with the `adapt()` function. When trying to join my dataset with the FeatureSpace I've made,

```
train_ds_with_no_labels = train_ds.map(lambda x, _: x)
feature_space.adapt(train_ds_with_no_labels)
```

I get these errors

```
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/feature_space.py:531, in FeatureSpace.adapt.<locals>.<lambda>(x)
    518     raise ValueError(
    519         "`adapt()` can only be called on a tf.data.Dataset. "
    520         f"Received instead: {dataset} (of type {type(dataset)})"
    521     )
    523 for name in self._list_adaptable_preprocessors():
    524     # Call adapt() on each individual adaptable layer.
    525 
   (...)
    528     # and call the layer's `_adapt_function` on each batch
    529     # to simulate the behavior of adapt() in a more performant fashion.
--> 531     feature_dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: x[name])
    532     preprocessor = self.preprocessors[name]

KeyError: 'sibsp'
```

and this takes us to

```
    518     raise ValueError(
    519         "`adapt()` can only be called on a tf.data.Dataset. "
    520         f"Received instead: {dataset} (of type {type(dataset)})"
    521     )
```

But when I did `type(dataset)`, I get `<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.map_op._MapDataset'>` which is exactly what the [code I'm following](https://keras.io/examples/structured_data/structured_data_classification_with_feature_space/) has.

The `train_with_no_labels` that I pass into adapt looks like this (just one sample)

```
{'PassengerId': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=80>, 'Pclass': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=3>, 'Name': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'Dowdell, Miss. Elizabeth'>, 'Sex': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'female'>, 'Age': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=30.0>, 'SibSp': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=0>, 'Parch': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=0>, 'Ticket': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'364516'>, 'Fare': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=12.475>} <class 'dict'>
```

and my `FeatureSpace` looks like this

```
from keras.utils import FeatureSpace

feature_space = FeatureSpace(
    features={
        # Categorical features encoded as integers
        "sibsp": FeatureSpace.integer_categorical(num_oov_indices=0), 
        "parch": FeatureSpace.integer_categorical(num_oov_indices=0),
        "pclass": FeatureSpace.integer_categorical(num_oov_indices=0),

        # Categorical feature encoded as string
        "sex": FeatureSpace.string_categorical(num_oov_indices=0),
        "embarked": FeatureSpace.string_categorical(num_oov_indices=0),
        
        # Numerical features to discretize
        "Age": FeatureSpace.float_discretized(num_bins=30), 
        
        # Numerical features to normalize
        "fare": FeatureSpace.float_normalized(),
    },
    output_mode="concat",
)
```

[Here's](https://www.kaggle.com/code/oliverkiranbrown/titanic-first-attempt) the notebook I've been working on and [here's](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/titanic) the dataset and further info about it. I'm very fresh to this but have been stuck for several days now. I've tried everything I can think of and searched all over online. Such a weird error, I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I can't see it. Are there better ways of going about this?